# Android OpenGL - image and position

Tags: android, opengl, position

I am making 2D android game with images (sprites, PNG) and I have 3 questions for OpenGL:

1. How to add an image from drawable folder?
2. How to change position of an image (element)?
3. How to get position (x, y) of an image (element)?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: see my answer, it can help you to understand how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791983/android-2d-game-with-opengl/18792153#18792153

Answer (score 0):

> How to add an image from drawable folder?

With `itmapFactory`

```
public void loadTextures(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ExplosionSprite :: loadTextures");  

    mFrame = 0;

    InputStream is;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.a1);


    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    gl.glGenTextures(TEXTURE_COUNT, textures, 0);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle(); 

}
```

where `R.drawable.a1` `a1` is image located under `res\drawable-xxx`

> How to change position of an image (element)?

Like with Canvas you have `X` and `Y`. But with specific transaction:

```
public void updateScreenData(float screenWidth, float screenHeight){
    // takes screen Height and Width
    this.mScreenWidth = (screenWidth > 0) ? screenWidth : 1f;
    this.mScreenHeight = screenHeight;
    wRatio = 10f/mScreenWidth;
    hRatio = mScreenHeight/10f;

}

public void draw(GL10 gl){

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    try {
        float transx =  + (wRatio * x);
        float transy =  + (mScreenHeight*wRatio) - (wRatio * y) - 1/hRatio;

        // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "transx: " + transx + "; transy: " + transy + "; sprite.x: "+  sprite.x + "; sprite.y: " + sprite.y);  

        gl.glTranslatef(transx, transy, 0.0f);

        //###########  draw ##############

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, floatBufferArray[mFrame]);

        update();
       gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //###############################

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
    gl.glPopMatrix();           
}
```

Full code example you can find <kbd>[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791983/android-2d-game-with-opengl/18792153#18792153)</kbd>

Answer (score -7):

This is how you add it.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b1" />
```

Comment: see the question, its not OpenGL,

Comment: so its not as you see